# Minimum machine requirement to setup a Ceph cluster

Tags: ceph

I need to setup a Ceph cluster for development purpose.

How many machines are required to setup a Ceph cluster? 
Can I setup a Ceph cluster on a single machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can install and run on a single node, however, the overhead in that case is large, without giving you resistance to a node failure. If one node is your end goal, try something like Zfs.